# Como comparar la fecha de un campo con fecha actual con Eloquent de Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Lo que intento es mostrar un numero de registros según la fecha de estos (los registros); que tienen que estar dentro de la fecha actual, es decir si hay algún registro que tiene una fecha distinta a la fecha actual, al contar los registros no debería aparecer dentro del resultado.

Por ejemplo en MySQL se tiene lo siguiente:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'COLUMNAS', tabla.fecha FROM tabla WHERE DATE(tabla.fecha) = CURDATE()
```

En donde, esta línea:

`DATE(tabla.fecha) = CURDATE()`

Es la que me devuelve, más el `COUNT(*)`, el numero de registros que coinciden dentro de la fecha de hoy.

Luego en LARAVEL, tengo el siguiente código:

```
$hoy = new DateTime();
$hoy->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$reserva_fecha = DB::table('reserva')->pluck('fecha_reserva');

//VARIABLE QUE CUENTA CANCHAS RESERVADAS POR USUARIO
    $book = DB::table('cancha')->join('complejo', 'cancha.complejo_id', '=', 'complejo.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.complejo_id','=', 'complejo.id')
        ->join('reserva', 'reserva.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orwhere('reserva.fecha_reserva', '<=', $hoy)
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as filas'))
        ->first();
//--
```

El cual al probar el resultado que devuelve `dd($book)`, resulta en:

```
{#430 ▼
  +"filas": 5
}
```

Siendo igual que la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que corresponde a mi base de datos. En donde los registros encontrados son **5**. Hasta ahí va todo bien.

Pero el problema surge cuando hay uno o varios registros en donde la fecha es menor que la fecha actual y la variable `$book` también me agrega esas fechas, dentro del `COUNT(*)` en cambio con MYSQL no cuenta las fechas anteriores. ¿Como podría lograr lo mismo pero en Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
use Carbon\Carbon; //Importa la clase Carbon hasta arriba de tu clase

$hoy = Carbon::today(); //Aquí se obtiene la fecha de hoy

$book = DB::table('cancha')->join('complejo', 'cancha.complejo_id', '=', 'complejo.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.complejo_id','=', 'complejo.id')
        ->join('reserva', 'reserva.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->whereDate('reserva.fecha_reserva', '<=', $hoy) //Where date se encarga de hacer la comparación entre fechas
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as filas'))
        ->first();
```

También, cómo sólo quieres saber el número de registros podrías omitir el `select` y hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$book = DB::table('cancha')->join('complejo', 'cancha.complejo_id', '=', 'complejo.id')
            ->join('users', 'users.complejo_id','=', 'complejo.id')
            ->join('reserva', 'reserva.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->whereDate('reserva.fecha_reserva', '<=', $hoy) //Where date se encarga de hacer la comparación entre fechas
            ->count();
```

Laravel ya trae instalado `Carbon`, el cual es una API extensión de `DateTime`, la cual, recomiendo ampliamante usarla

Comment: Gracias, por responder, mira probé aquello y funcionó. Solo que cambié el `<=` por un `=` para que me cuente los registros según la fecha actual.

Comment: @M4uriXD ¿Qué te funcionó?

Comment: Lo que buscaba, contar la cantidad de registros según la fecha actual. Porque en mi sitio iba a poner un contador de reservas por dia.

Comment: @M4uriXD Ah ya jaja me confundí un poco con tu comparación porque querías una cosa y en tu código decía otra, pero que bueno que te sirvió